# asp.net change cell value on gridview with code behind

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net gridview with several rows/pages.

There are some fields below it which display full details of the row which has been clicked on gridview.

I then change a field value on the details below area and the new data is saved programmatically to database.

However the value on the gridview just changed below, doesn't change.

I would like to just change de cell value on the gridview programmatically so there is no need to reload the data grid.

I am basically looking for something like:

```
 GridView1Row.row(currentrow).column(5)="xxxx"
```

I've search around and found some solutions based on _onrowdatabound but this is not correct, as I just want to change one cell of the grid.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to change the value in your datasource and then binding the datasource to the grid again. (don't reload it from the database just change the value in the datasource)

Comment: I appreciate your comments. But binding the datasource to the grid again doesn't that reload the data again, which is what I am trying to avoid ?  The database is changed via code (when a textbox changes) using a SQL query...but the data on gridview row doesn't....that's why I want to change it via code without binding the datasource again or refreshing the gridview.

Comment: what i'm suggesting is altering the datatable in your code behind to match your change and then binding the datagrid to that datatable, **not** fetching data from the database again. (if you could provide more information, perhaps a code sample of what you exactly do, maybe i could be of more help), sometihng like `DataTable dt = whateverdatasource;AlterDataTable(dt);grid.datasource = dt; grid.databind();`

Comment: Ok,  I understand now, sorry. The thing is that the gridview shows various pages. So I might be in page 3, row 5.
If I bind the datasource again (after change made as you suggest) wouldn't then the gridview display page 1 again ?

Comment: i'm not sure if it does, but even if so, you can set the page using grid.PageIndex property